# Making Animation For Player

Tags: pygame

So I'm making a game but using the number 1-9 images for the animation and I need help with the animation and it says things that I don't know
"IndexError: list index out of range"

Code:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    player_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Images/Animation_survivor/Move")
    player_animation = {}
    player_animation["nor"] = []

    @staticmethod
    def init():
        for i in range(9):
            filename = "survivor-move_rifle_{}.png".format(i)
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(Player.player_folder, filename))
            org = pygame.transform.scale(img, (37, 37))

            Player.player_animation["nor"].append(org)
    def __init__(self, size):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = Player.player_animation[size][0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = 40
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (80, 68))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 90)
        self.rect.bottom = Game.HEIGHT - 10
        self.rect.centerx = Game.WIDTH / 2
        self.shoot_delay = 150
        self.last_shoot = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.size = size
```

Comment: Yo need to call `Player.init()` before `self.image = Player.player_animation[size][0]`

Answer (score 0):

An index error usually indicates that you try to access a collection (like an array/ list) with an index thats higher than the number of elements in it.
For example:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Would get an index error on

```
array[3]
```

since it has only 3 elements (indexed 0, 1, 2)

For example, is Player.player_animation[size][0] even initialized anywhere? Because if it is empty, there is no index 0 (which would be the first element).

Make sure to properly initialize your lists and that there are elements in them, for example with:

```
if not Player.player_animation[size]:
  self.image = **dummyImage**
```

Comment: or just use an empty list and if it is empty don't access any indexes at all